# Running a project on a machine with Visual Studio and on a machine without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, deployment

I have a C# WinForms project that measure some performance readings of our project APIs. Then, I have a machine on which I have to take performance measurements.

I have 2 ways to perform the task:

1. On a machine where Visual Studio is installed.
2. On a machine where Visual Studio is not installed.

I have already compiled the project, and so, I will be running the program from EXE file in bin\debug folder.

In my thinking, the performance measurements will not differ in both of the above environments as long as Visual Studio instance (devenv.exe) is not running in the machine.

Do you think that even when Visual Studio instance (devenv.exe) is not running in the system, the winforms program will report slower performance readings?

**Note**: I prefer having VS installed because it helps debug some code errors some times.

Comment: For urgent help please call 911 or local emergency number. Please also read http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ and consider making your question a bit more concrete. SO is not really best place to guess whether your code will be faster or slower on particular machine than your current one.

Answer (score 0):

A. compile it to release.

B. run without VS. you don't need it to run the program, just the dot net run time.

C. the performance reading is not affected by the existence of Visual Studio.

D. If the machine is very short in RAM, the less program running will yield better performance. if RAM is not a problem - you can easily run with Visual Studio, in Debug or in Release. depending on your logic just test to see if any performance degradation occur.

E. If you the machine is short in RAM / SPACE and you still want to debug setup remote debugging.... you can run the program on one machine and debug from another....